# Duda sobre Arrays Bidimensionales en Problema de Salto del Caballo

Tags: java

Anteriormente hice el ***salto del caballo*** usando *Arrays* en **Java**. Pero ahora les comentare mi siguiente problema:

Los movimientos de caballo se hacen mediante una impresion de *Arrays*, la cual son estos:

```
        String[][] izquierdo = { { "1", "-", "-","-" },
                                 { "1", "-", "-","-" }, 
                                 { "1", "1", "-","-" }, 
                                 { "-", "-", "-","-" } };

     String[][] abajoIzquierdo = { { "-", "-", "-", "-" }, 
                                   { "-", "-", "-", "-" }, 
                                   { "1", "-", "-", "-" },
                                   { "1", "1", "1", "-" }};

    String[][] arribaIzquierdo = { { "1", "1", "1", "-" }, 
                                   { "1", "-", "-", "-" }, 
                                   { "-", "-", "-", "-" }, 
                                   { "-", "-", "-","-" }};

        String[][] arribaDerecho = { { "-", "-", "1", "1" }, 
                                     { "-", "-", "-", "1" }, 
                                     { "-", "-", "-", "1" }, 
                                     { "-", "-", "-","-" }};
```

Como pueden observar se **imprimen** estos *cuatro arrays* en los siguientes movimientos: izquierdo, abajoIzquierdo, arribaIzquierdo y arribaDerecho.

Luego se **ingreso** las siguientes *Variables*:

```
    String izquierda = "a";
    String abajo = "s";
    String arriba = "w";
    String arribaDerecha = "d";
```

Estas *Variables*, al ser seleccionadas mediante el teclado se mostrara ***la pocision del caballo*** de los **Arrays** que fueron hechos, esto quiere decir:

- Si se elije la tecla "**a**" se mostrara el *Array* "**izquierdo**".
- Si se elije la tecla "**s**" se mostrara el *Array* "**abajoIzquierdo**".
- Si se elije la tecla "**w**" se mostrara el *Array* "**arribaIzquierdo**".
- Si se elije la tecla "**d**" se mostrara el *Array* "**arribaDerecho**".

Para que se demuestre la impresion dentro de consola para cada uno de estos *Arrays* se utilizo esta parte del codigo (que es aqui donde imprime el arreglo "***izquierdo***"):

```
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Que tecla Desea pocisionar al caballo ( se visualizara por la letra: C)?:");

                String valor = input.next();
if (izq.equals(valor)) {

                System.out.println("\n***¡¡EL CABALLO SE MOVIO A LA IZQUIERDA!!***\n");
                for (int x = 0; x < izquierdo.length; x++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < izquierdo[x].length; y++)
                        System.out.print(" | " + izquierdo[x][y] + " | ");
                    System.out.println("\n----------------------------");

                }
```

Ahora lo que les pido de su ayuda es que me enseñen a reemplazar estos cuatro **Arrays Bidimensionales** de gran escala por otros u otro donde ejecute la funcion sin tener que recurrir a imprimirlos, como un ejemplo:

Al elegir la tecla "**w**" no me imprima el array "**arribaIzquierdo**", mas bien que me cree dicho **Array** dandome la pocision que se tiene establecida tal y como se ve en los arreglos, enseñando asi en consola donde se encuentra el caballo ubicado.

Sin mas que decir compañeros, en espera de su ayuda, estare al tanto con sus comentarios. Gracias.

Comment: A ver si lo entiendo bien. Quieres que lo que son los patrones de movimiento no estén en el código, si no que se genere según lo que se indique y en que posición estaba el caballo, ¿no? pero quieres que se vea todo el movimiento que hace, no solo la posición final. Si todo es si, ¿hay alguna variable que contenga la posición del caballo?

Comment: Hola Cadeq, la respuesta es no, todo es directamente a impresion de Arrays, la cual se imprimen al seleccionar las letras que mencione (a,s,w,d). Tambien no me importa mucho que muestre todo el movimiento, solo me importa mostrar la posicion final.

Comment: Si conservas la posición del caballo en un array de tamaño dos`int[] pos = new Integer[2]` donde esta la posición en X e Y, a base de incrementos y decrementos de estos, se puede sacar la posición final. al final ¿quieres imprimir solo la posición o todo el tablero con la posición del caballo en este? Con esta ultima pregunta debería de poder responderte apropiadamente.

Comment: Hola Cadeq, me ayudarias con imprimir todo el tablero con la posición del caballo. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{

```
final static char a = 'a',
d = 'd',
w = 'w',
s = 's',
salir = 'e';/*
creamos variables de tipo caracter que contienes
los movimientos de caballo y la de salir...
estos son los tipocos del teclado normal:
a: iquierda
d: derecha
w: arriba
s: abajo
e: salir -> exit...

son finales para que no se les pueda asignar otro valor por error y
estadisticos para que no nesesiten una instancia.
*/

final static String[][] izquierdo = { { "1", "-", "-","-" },
    { "1", "-", "-","-" }, 
    { "1", "1", "-","-" }, 
    { "-", "-", "-","-" } },
    abajoIzquierdo = { { "-", "-", "-", "-" }, 
    { "-", "-", "-", "-" }, 
    { "1", "-", "-", "-" },
    { "1", "1", "1", "-" }},
    arribaIzquierdo = { { "1", "1", "1", "-" }, 
    { "1", "-", "-", "-" }, 
    { "-", "-", "-", "-" }, 
    { "-", "-", "-","-" }},
    arribaDerecho = { { "-", "-", "1", "1" }, 
    { "-", "-", "-", "1" }, 
    { "-", "-", "-", "1" }, 
    { "-", "-", "-","-" }};/*
    estos son la movientos decaballo...
    la verdad solo lo copie y pege de tu piblicacion..
    aun no le entiendo muy bien.
    pero a mi paraces fuera sido mejor matrixes de caracteres char[][]...
    */
public static void main(String[] args){//primer metodo en ejectarce y que llama al resto...

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);//creamos una nueva variable de tipo Scanner y la instaciamos con la estrada del sistema.
    while(true){//para que el bucle siempre permanezca activo hasta que se detenga por dentro.
        char mov = sc.next().toCharArray()[0];/*el hilo se detiene hasta que se imgrese algo al sistema
        en este punto se puede meter una String pero nosotros solo consideramos en primero...
        por ejemplo:
        si escribe "exit" o "e" es lo mismo porque solo consideramos el primero caracter...
        */
        if(mov == salir)break;//si el primero caractor es "e" salimos de bucle y por ende tambien del programa.

        printMovimiento(mov);// si el caractor no fue "e" sino otro pasamos aimprimir...
        //si el caracter pasado no es ningun movimiento {a,s,d,w} causara un error...

        String[][] movimiento = getMovimiento(mov);/* 
        bueno esto es donde va tu codigo segun tu cambeniencia...
         //si el caracter pasado no es ningun movimiento {a,s,d,w} causara un error...
        */
    }
}

private static void printMovimiento(char mov)
{
    String[][] movimiento = getMovimiento(mov);//si el caracter pasado no es ningun movimiento {a,s,d,w} causara un error...

    String strMov = "\n***¡¡EL CABALLO SE MOVIO ";
    switch(mov){// aqui solo definimos que tipo de movimiento es...
        case a:
            strMov += "A LA IZQUIERDA!!***\n";break;
        case s:
            strMov += "ABAJO A LA IZQUIERDA!!***\n";break;
        case w:
            strMov += "ARRIBA A LA IZQUIERDA!!***\n";break;
        case d:
            strMov += "ARRIBA A LA DERECHA!!***\n";
    }
    System.out.println(strMov);//imprimimos el tipo de movimeinto.

    for (int x = 0; x < movimiento.length; x++) {// este es tu cadigo donde imprimes el moviemiento
        for (int y = 0; y < movimiento[x].length; y++)
            System.out.print(" | " + izquierdo[x][y] + " | ");
        System.out.println("\n----------------------------");

    }
}

public static String[][] getMovimiento(char c){// sierve para retorna el tipo de moviento 
    switch(c){
        case a:
            return izquierdo;
        case s:
            return abajoIzquierdo;
        case w:
            return arribaIzquierdo;
        case d:
            return arribaDerecho;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("El caracter: "+c+",no es valido para hacer un movimiento");/*
            causa el error y nos dice que el caracater ? no es valido para hacer un movimiento.
            */
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Bienvenido a S.O en español Cristhian. ¿Podrías ayudarnos explicando tu código? Mientras más completa sea la respuesta, a más personas podrás ayudar en este sitio.

Comment: Hola Cristian, de hecho el problema son los Arrays que establecen los patrones de movimiento (izquierdo,abajoIzquierdo,arribaIzquierdo y arribaDerecho) y hacer que se generen. Ya que como vez al seleccionar dicha tecla, imprime el Array que le corresponde y quisiera que haga lo mismo pero que genere el patron.

Answer (score 0):

Vale, vamos a suponer que tenemos dos constantes `altura` y `ancho` que definen el tamaño del tablero.

**AVISO: solo estoy poniendo los movimientos posibles de tu ejemplo. El caballo tiene un total de 8 movimientos posibles**

Esto lo tendremos de primeras declarado a nivel de clase

```
int altura=8;
int ancho=8;
int pos[] = new Integer[2]{3,3};//Colocamos el caballo en la posición inicial (en este caso, el centro)
```

Luego en el método correspondiente al código que pusiste:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Que tecla Desea pocisionar al caballo ( se visualizara por la letra: C)?:");
String valor = input.next();
switch(valor)
{
   //Cada tecla ara un desplazamiento en X e Y con respecto a la posición del caballo
   case("w"):move(2,-1);break;
   case("a"):move(-1,-2)break;
   case("s"):move(2,1)break;
   case("d"):move(1,2)break;
   default: System.out.println("Valor no valido");break;
}

for (int x = 0; x < anch; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < alto; y++)
    {
        if( x == pos[0] && y == pos[1])
        {
           System.out.print(" | C | ");
        }
        else
        {
           System.out.println(" | - | ");
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("\n----------------------------");

//Creamos un método nuevo que calcule si el movimiento es posible
public void move(int x, int y)
{
   if(pos[0]+x>=0 
      && pos[0]+x<ancho
      && pos[1]+y>=0
      && pos[1]+y<alto)
   {
      pos[0]=pos[0]+x;
      pos[1]=pos[1]+y;
   }
   else
   {
     //Llegado aqui, la ficha se saldria del tablo, así que no permitimos el movimiento y se queda donde esta
     System.out.println("Movimiento imposible de realizar")
   }
}
```

---

Con este ejemplo un movimiento `izquierdo` debería de dar como resultado:

```
| - || - || - || - || - || - || - || - | 
| - || - || C || - || - || - || - || - |
| - || - || - || - || - || - || - || - |
| - || - || - || - || - || - || - || - |
| - || - || - || - || - || - || - || - |
| - || - || - || - || - || - || - || - |
| - || - || - || - || - || - || - || - |
| - || - || - || - || - || - || - || - |
```

No he podido probar el código en un entorno, pero debería de valerte.